# Bento4, instance management (create/release)

Tags: c++

I want to use Bento4 to parse MP4 file and check if they have 1 or several track.

```
    AP4_ByteStream* inputFileStream = NULL;
    AP4_Result res = AP4_FileByteStream::Create(file.c_str(), AP4_FileByteStream::STREAM_MODE_READ, inputFileStream);
    if(res != AP4_SUCCESS || inputFileStream == NULL) {throw std::logic_error("Error while analyzing " + file);}

    AP4_File inputFileParser(*inputFileStream);
    AP4_Movie* pMovie = inputFileParser.GetMovie();
    const AP4_List< AP4_Track >& trackList = pMovie->GetTracks();
    inputFileStream->Release();
    return (trackList.ItemCount()>1);
```

The class AP4_FileByteStream provide the create function and has its dtor protected, thats why there is a `release` function.

But in that case I use pointer and const reference coming from the parser initialized with that FileByteStream. How can we expect that the `return (trackList.ItemCount()>1);` work after the `release` ?

Based on the experiment I made, it works, but I may be lucky !
Have you any idea ?
I thought about putting the `inputFileStream` as a `shared_ptr` to release the resources only after the return evaluation. Is it more secure ?

Comment: there is no Bento4 tag and I have not enough reputation to create it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything wrong with simply

```
bool hasMultipleTracks = trackList.ItemCount() > 1;
inputFileStream->Release();
return hasMultipleTracks;
```

Comment: yes, agree it's the easiest way to be safe! but that factory/release model is really a pain....